# Какой View и какой формат подойдет лучше для вставки большого текста с форматированием?

Tags: android, kotlin

Нужно в фрагмент вставить довольно большой кусок текста, вероятно будет скрол. Какой View и какой формат подойдет лучше для вставки большого текста? Обычный TextView или может рендерить в формате html ? Текст будет с форматированием шрифта (жирность, размер, цвет, абзацы....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно простого `TextView` с использованием класса `Html`.

```
val sourceString = "<b>" + "text" + "</b>" + "more text"
textView.text = Html.fromHtml(sourceString)
```

Comment: забыл уточнить что текст будет с форматированием шрифта (жирность, размер, цвет, абзацы....)

Comment: Конечно подойдёт, только высоту и ширину установите закрепленную.

Comment: а как же потом шрифт форматировать? В html можно теги использовать ( <.>), а в андроиде?

Comment: В таком случае вам удобнее будет использовать HTML. `String sourceString = "<b>" + "text" + "</b> + "more text"; `
`mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));`

Comment: понятно, спасибо. Получается что сначала нужно будет собрать переменную sourceString ... А если текст большой - не хотелось бы весь его записывать в код. Есть ли возможность выводить уже готовый файл с текстом? Например в формате pdf, word, html...?

Comment: `Html.fromHtml(source)`, где `source` -- строка html. По сути да, вы можете любым способом засунуть html текст. Тут смотрите сами, как вам удобнее, но по моему мнению использовать сторонние файлы вроде pdf и word будет слишком громоздко.

Comment: а если создать отдельный файл, в котором будет собираться sourse - надо же как-то будет передать эту переменную в фрагмент... Получается что нужна публичная переменная, которую фрагмент считает из этого файла

Comment: Да, можно из файла. Вот пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android

Comment: так, понял. Но один момент - *.txt - файлы не поддерживают форматирование текста.

Comment: Вам достаточно считывать их, форматировать, и перезаписывать обратно.

Comment: наверно это будет сложно. Мне нужно будет какие-то части текста выделить жирным шрифтом или другим цветом, добавить красную строку.... Хотелось бы сразу отформатировать, типа как в Word, и потом выводить на экран

Comment: Смотрите сами), я вам предложил реализацию textview с HTML, думаю дальше вы справитесь

Comment: да спасибо, остановлюсь на html

Comment: Отметьте тогда ответ решением, пожалуйста

Comment: конечно, но надо ваш пост оформить как ответ "В таком случае вам удобнее будет использовать HTML. String sourceString = "<b>" + "text" + "</b> + "more text";  mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));" И кстати для котлина этот код подойдёт или надо изменить будет?

Comment: Отредактировал и добавил пример на Kotlin

Comment: К слову, в Android Studio встроен конвертер с Java на Kotlin, поэтому можно ничего не менять

Comment: знаю, но он у меня срабатывает только когда вставляю кусок кода на java. А есть возможность перекомпилировать сразу целый файл ? А если я в файл .txt загоню текст с разметкой html - как потом его отобразить? Что-то вроде R.id.file_name

Comment: Или как здесь - но только нужно на kotlin http://java-online.ru/java-file.xhtml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157876/read-html-file-from-assets/11158424 перекомпилируйте на Котлин потом

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогли )